# Difference between NGramFilterFactory and EdgeNGramFilterFactory

Tags: solr, search-engine, tokenize, n-gram, filterfactory

I am a beginner in Solr. In  my project, `NGramFilterFactory` and `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`, both are being used for a field. My understanding as per the document is `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` is used for "starts with" query while `NGramFilterFactory` is suitable for "contains" query.

I indexed a small dataset for both combinations (one in which I used only `NGramFilterFactory` and in another I used both `NGramFilterFactory` and `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`) but I did not see any difference in the output.

If my understanding is correct, in a way `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` is a subset of `NGramFilterFactory`. If this is true then is there any benefit of using both types of filters on the same field?

Comment: did you had a read here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter

Comment: Yes, I already referred this document but I want to be 100% sure that removing `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` wont affect result as this change is going to be in production.

Comment: I would suggest try analysis of it using the solr analysis tool. That gives you clear idea of how indexing output would be ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not be using both filters on the same field, they will completely mess up your matching. If you need to match in a middle of a token, you use NGrams. If you only need to match from the start, you use EdgeNGrams. Never both together.

Comment: The matching from the end is deprecated and - in later Solr - does not work. If matching from the end is required, a reversing filter should be used in both analysis and query chains.

Comment: Ah, good point. I forgot that. The wiki really needs to be updated.